# how to update homebrew with Cron on Mac os

Tags: linux, macos, bash, cron

I've been discvering some long lasting linux techs to help automate my daily work. I found `cron` to be very powerful if I can use it to check the updates of some packages I have on my system.

For example, I want to update my `Homebrew` everyday at 11pm. What I did is, with `sudo crontab -u user -e`, I opened up `crontab` in Vim. And I put following commands into it, to make updates for `homebrew` and send me an email.

Here's the code:

```
MAILTO=myemail@foo.com
* 23 * * * brew update
```

and I save it to wait for magic happens. Instead of excuting this command, in the email I recieved, it says `/bin/sh: brew : command not found`

But when I type `/bin/sh` in terminal to open `sh` and type in `brew update` it will update the `Homebrew`。

What did I do wrong with my `crontab` configuration?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Using `crontab` seems deprecated on Darwin (Mac OS X is based on Darwin). Use `launchd` instead. This is one of many quick tutorials: http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs

Comment: not sure if you wanted to execute every minute of the 11th hour... you're probably getting a lot of emails between 11 and 12

Comment: Just to add on @rjmoggach's comment, OP probably meant to do `00 23 * * * brew update`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A cronjob is a good option, but I didn't want it to happen automatically. I found a [script](http://chrisstreeter.com/archive/2012/08/homebrew-package-update-notifications-on-mountain-lion.html) that will notify you if a new version of a formula installed on your Mac is available.

I extended the [script](https://gist.github.com/SimonSimCity/13832e2e03597a6be793) to not show pinned formulae in the notifier.

I decided to use a launchd-agent for the cronjb, because this also runs if Mac is started later. Cron-jobs just run if your mac is already on at that time.

For a comparison of cronjob vs launchd, I recommend reading [this](http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs).

Here's my configuration which runs every day at 10am and 3pm. The script, called by the agent, is located at `/usr/local/bin/homebrew-update-notifier`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.simonsimcity.update-notifier</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/homebrew-update-notifier</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/homebrew.simonsimcity.update-notifier.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/homebrew.simonsimcity.update-notifier.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>15</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You will now be notified if a new update is available. Call `brew upgrade` if you feel outdated, or include it in the script.

Answer (score 31):

Cron doesn't have your PATH defined, make sure you always call commands with the full path, which is probably `/usr/local/bin/brew update`

This is considered good practice to keep unwanted/unexpected commands from running.  If someone put a malicious script called 'brew' somewhere else in your path, but before /usr/local/bin, it would get called instead.

Comment: Thanks @Donovan, this one worked. Now I know where to configure my `crontab`. a lot thanks

Comment: Note that the path might be different (mine is at `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`). Run `which brew` in your shell to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your `bash` configuration.  Make sure you set the `PATH` so that it contains the directory that `brew` is in.  You may have it set in your `~/.profile` but make sure it's also set in your `~/.bashrc`.  Alternatively, you could set it in your `crontab` in the same way you set `MAILTO`

Comment: Looking at Ian's question, it says that cron is using `/bin/sh` as its shell rather than `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally the way I handle this is:

- Download CronniX (it's discontinued but still works, e.g. `brew cask install cronnix`)
- Setup the job within the UI via `/usr/local/bin/brew update` to run every hour.

Let it tick over in the background!

[image]